# добавление удаление блоков WordPress

Tags: wordpress, админка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как реализовать добавление и удаление вот таких блоков через админку WordPress

Comment: Каких "таких"? Где, для чего, что выводить? Отредактируй вопрос - уточни задачи и функционал.

Comment: @SeVlad сделайте мне красиво